# iPhone InApp Purchase problem - canMakePayments always fails

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I've searched hard for this issue and there were similar questions but couldn't find answers to my issue.

The problems is that '[SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]' always fails. The code is extremely simple as follows.

```
if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) //
{ 
    NSLog(@"able to make payments");
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:g_custom_store_observer]; // Register the observer

    SKMutablePayment *myPayment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProductIdentifier: strItemName];
    myPayment.quantity = 2;
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:myPayment];
}
else{
    NSLog(@"not able to make it");
    return KD_FALSE;
}
```

I think I missed something in the testing process. What I did so far was

- Registered my app to iTunesConnect (Created a new App, and checked the Bundle ID)
- Set up the 'Rights and Pricing', mine is 'free' app
- Added 'consumable Items' from the 'Manage In-App purchases' menu on the iTunesConnect.
  filled all the text fields, uploaded image for review, and all of them are in '  Waiting for Review  ' status now.
- created a test user
- Rebuilt(cleand and build) my App, checking the Bundle ID, code-signed with proper distribution certificate. the bundle ID is exactly the same as the one shown in the App details on the iTunesConnect page.
- Uploaded my newly built App to the iTunesConnect (Uploaded binary, no code-signe error) and now is in 'Waiting For Review' status.
- Now I wanted to check the In-App purchase work or not, I ran debug version of my App on my iPad device. It's built in Debug mode, code-signed with my developer certificate, exactly the same code uploaded to iTunesConnect.
- On my iPad, I logged out from iTunesStore
- Ran my App
- When I trigger the code above, 'canMakePayments' always fail.

The only thing different from other normal iPhone Apps is that mine is OpenGl based game, so the most of the codes are written in C++, interfacing with iPhone platform specific stuffs written in ObjectiveC/C++.

So the code above is called from C++ module, and no iOS specific UIViewController is not created yet. Do I need UIViewController before I call [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments] ??

Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I am so ashamed and embarrassed that it was totally my mistake... :$

I followed again the instructions here
http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/
(Thanks 'Troy') but no gain...
I tried revoking and re-issuing certificates and provision profiles, building and uploading my App to AppStore.. I wasted days.

And Finally I found what was the problem. :$

The problem was my iPad setting.. (Setting->General->Restrictions)
I remember very long back I enabled the restrictions to avoid my kids' mistake to buy comercial stuffs...

Sorry guys for this mess.. :$

Answer (score 0):

That is what the documentation of canMakePayments says: It returns YES if the user of the device has the permission to make any payments whatsoever. You don't need to have set up anything about payments, or have set up anything about payments correctly, to call this method. It goes directly to check the settings on your device.

As a developer, you should check this before you show any payment related user interface to adapt to the fact that the user cannot make any payments. And check on a development device whether your app behaves reasonably well if the user cannot make payments.